# Impedance of V Antenna as Function of Angle

Tags: antenna-theory, impedance

I'm trying to experimentally investigate the radiation resistance of a v-shaped antenna. When it's fully unfolded and the reactance is at resonance, the resistance is about 73Ω. When it's folded, it acts similar to an open coaxial cable.

I'm wondering if there's a more general description of impedance for the v-shaped antenna as a function of the angle between the wires. I've tried looking through Antenna Theory: Analysis and Design by Balanis, but I couldn't find something. Are there any papers or textbooks out there that have the answer?

Answer (score 1):

This sort of questions is probably best answered by modeling an antenna using either a NEC2 or NEC4 model. There are a variety of such packages available for this for DOS, Windows and Mac.

That makes for much easier experimentation rather than having to cut and raise a lot of wire!